# Programa en Android que sea como una ventana pequeña

Tags: java, android, modal, ventana

me han encargado hacer un programa para Android que interactue con otro. Es decir, está el programa A, que llama al programa B. El programa B debe ser solo una pequeña ventana en donde se ingresen datos y al aceptar se debe volver al programa A.

No encontré info al respecto, alguien podría orientarme como realizar esto? 
Todo lo que encuentro e intento se trata de apps de ventana entera a las que se les puede agregar un Dialog, pero no encuentro como hacer que una app entera sea solo un pequeño Dialog.

Soy novata en Android, la versión en el gradle me dijeron que debería ser: minSdkVersion 19.

Gracias

Comment: Qué versión de Android? Intentaste algo? (ya nos dijiste que no encontraste info, pero no sabemos si intentaste alguna cosa)

Comment: Ahi edite y respondi, gracias!

Comment: Hola!
Cuando te refieres a "programas" entiendo que es a pantallas, cierto?

Comment: Si! en la app A (que es de otra empresa) se rellenan unos datos, esa app va a llamar a la app B (la de mi empresa) en donde se deben completar otros lados.. y luego volver a continuar el flujo en la app A. Como es medios de pago y se maneja info sensible se decidio hacer el pago en 2 apps de 2 empresas. Mi app deberia ser solo un pequeño cuadro de dialogo, no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, solo de hacer una pantalla entera con los textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sobre comunicaciones entre dos apps distintas no creo que se pueda indirectamente. 
pero aportare sobre como hacer tu actitivy se muestre como un dialog.

declaras tu activity y le pones el theme

```
<activity
            android:name=".abc"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" />
```

tu style es tan simple como

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    </style>
```

Comment: Funciono muchas gracias!!